# Is it safe to put user-conrolled strings in a HTTP Location header?

Tags: http, url-redirection

I am thinking of adding URL shortening to my site.

Let's say my database has already stored `url` as a plain string, this data was provided by the user and is arbitrary.

So a naive implementation in PHP might look a bit like this

```
$url = lookup_url ($_POST['url_id']);
if (null !== $url)
{
     header ("Location: ".encode_url($url));
     exit ();
}
```

with a suitable [encode_url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085904/is-ok-to-urlencode-the-value-in-headerlocation-value) to ensure the user-supplied data is confined to the `Location` header and doesn't leak into the rest of the HTTP response or inject into the database or whatever.

Are there any security vulnerabilities in doing a redirect to an arbitrary user-supplied URL?

**EDIT** to clarify, in response to @UTF-8's sensible observation -- assume the user doesn't directly interact with the page they are redirected-to. Can an attacker break my security if the user follows the link and does nothing else?

Comment: Who would be vulnerable? Your site? The user submitting the string?

Comment: [Unvalidated redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) is usually considered a vulnerability - although URL shorteners deliberately allow this. You also need to strip line breaks to avoid [HTTP response splitting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Response_Splitting)

Comment: Is the user provided string validated against an allowable set of characters?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't safe. It's dangerous.

A phisher can send an email to your users and and have them click onto a link leading to `https://yourwebsite.com/something/something/script.php?someVariable=doesntMatterBecaucseItWontBeRead&someOtherVariable=onlyDesignedToMakeTheUrlLonger&url=https%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsitec.om%2Fsomethinng%2Fsomething%2Fi%2Fdont%2Fcare`

Users won't read nor understand that URL. They'll just have a quick look at it – in the best case – and see that it leads to `https://yourwebsite.com`, so everything is good in their opinions. Then, there is a whole lot of stuffing no one cares about. In the end, the get variable `url` is defined, starting with `https%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsitec.om` which is url encoded and when decoded is `https://yourwebsitec.om`. Notice that the TLD ending is `.om`, not `.com`. `.om` is the TLD ending for Oman and used a lot for phishing (or at least that's my personal impression).

The phisher can simply make the website the user is redirected to look like yours an then get their login information or other personal details from them.

Comment: So this is a social attack rather than a purely technical one. Suppose my site shows a YOU ARE LEAVING THE SITE warning page before following the link. I guess I'm asking: are there any security problems which arise *even if the user doesn't interact with the newly-visited page*?

Comment: Apart from that not being any post or get information if you're able to show such a warning, yes, that would still be a threat, even though ideally it shouldn't be. That's because ideally browsers are perfect sand boxes and they in fact are really good ones. However, from time to time (or all the time if you use flash or java), there are exploits which simply require the user to visit a web page in order for the attacker to be able to do some nasty stuff. Your site could still help an attacker to make users visit such a page as it looks like a page of a website they trust.

Comment: Is stackexchange subject to this, or do they have a defence that you are aware of?

Comment: @spraff - Not *purely* a social engineering attack.  If you simply serve the resulting URL inside `Location:` (as your question suggests) then CSRF is completely possible.  i.e. your website can be used as a hop into making users fall for CSRF on other (unrelated) websites.

Comment: Can you point to a concrete example?